# How to get Kafka client metrics from the Vert.x Kafka producer client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x, micrometer

I'm new to Vert.x and relatively new to Kafka.

How would I set up my Vert.x KafkaProducer to export Prometheus metrics?

At the moment, I can enable Prometheus metrics such as `vertx_http_server_request_bytes_max` and get view them through the webserver with:

```java
// simplified

import io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducer;
// ...
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(
    new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
        .setPrometheusOptions(new VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
        .setEnabled(true)));
// ...
// set up HttpServer then add a route for the metrics
Router.router(vertx).route("/metrics").handler(PrometheusScrapingHandler.create());
// ...
// create a new io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer.create(vertx, config);
```

Prior to using Vert.x, I could use the Apache KafkaProducer and bind KafkaClientMetrics like this:

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.kafka.KafkaClientMetrics;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
// ...
// after creating a producer
new KafkaClientMetrics(producer).bindTo(BackendRegistries.getDefaultNow());
```

Any suggestions for how I can get the usual Kafka client metrics, e.g. `kafka_producer_buffer_total_bytes` and others from  for the Vert.x KafkaProducer?

UPDATE: Following Jonatan's suggestion of looking at the code to create a SharedProducer, I've managed to get the following to work:

```java
KafkaWriteStream<String, String> stream = KafkaWriteStream.create(vertx, config);

// unwrap to get org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
Producer<String, String> apacheProducer = stream.unwrap();

// create io.vertx.kafka.client.producer.KafkaProducer
KafkaProducer vertxProducer = (new KafkaProducerImpl(vertx, stream)).registerCloseHook();

// set up metrics
MeterRegistry registry = BackendRegistries.getDefaultNow();
new KafkaClientMetrics(apacheProducer).bindTo(registry);
```

I've tested this by triggering the vertxProducer.send() and monitoring the Prometheus metrics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68994035/16715737 Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micrometer is creating a `Meter` for every Kafka `Metric`. It acquires them by just calling [`producer.metrics()`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer.html#metrics--) (look into [`KafkaClientMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaClientMetrics.java)). With this, your options are:

1. Getting a reference for the Kafka `Producer` from the vert.x Kafka client (check the `SharedProducer` in the vertx kafka client)
2. Ask the vert.x maintainers to provide a `metrics()` method
3. Ask the vert.x maintainers to instrument their client
4. Take a look at the old instrumentation of the Kafka binder in micrometer, it used JMX to create meters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jonatan. Looks like if I create a KafkaWriteStream, I can both create a vertx KafkaProducer from it and unwrap it to give me the Apache Producer. Will investigate further.

Comment: I've updated the question with the test I ran which follows Jonatan's suggestion to look at the KafkaProducer code for creating a shared producer. Thanks!